# React Native fetch() returns empty response body for HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, react-native, request, fetch

I'm working on a React Native application and I'm trying to fetch and parse the HTML data of the following website: 'https://menus.princeton.edu/dining/_Foodpro/online-menu/menuDetails.asp?sdtdate=12%2F09%2F2019&locationNum=02'. The page is non-empty (it displays the food menu of a particular dining hall at Princeton University), and a simple Postman request returns the HTML. However, when I try to fetch the HTML on my RN application, the request returns an empty body with status 200. The code I use for the fetch request is:

```
let url = 'https://menus.princeton.edu/dining/_Foodpro/online-menu/menuDetails.asp?sdtdate=12%2F09%2F2019&locationNum=02';
fetch(url)
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
      return(response.text());
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
```

In the console, however, I see the following output:

[image: Console Log Output]

The problem here is that even though the request is successful, it returns *undefined* instead of the HTML. The fetch() request works on webpages of other dining halls (e.g. https://menus.princeton.edu/dining/_Foodpro/online-menu/menuDetails.asp?sdtdate=12%2F09%2F2019&locationNum=03), so I'm not sure what's causing the error.

Comment: Still haven't found a workaround for this issue. Does anyone know how I can solve this problem?